# How to create full screen MaterialAlertDialog

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am trying to show a full screen alert dialog like the one on the material design website: [Full Screen Material Alert Dialog](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1Xlq7_lXkjBJDE6arihpaS3YWm4TSf2-S%2Fdialogs-fullscreen-behavior.mp4)

I created a

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
   .setTitle("Title")
   .setMessage("Message")
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", null)
   .show();
```

which works perfectly. However I want the dialog to appear as full screen with the toolbar and x button, so I can place `EditText`s inside the dialog.

I tried using the other constructor `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, theme)` but I cannot find a theme that will make the dialog appearance full screen. Is there a theme that makes the dialog full screen or do I have to do something else to make it full screen?

Comment: Are you sure it's a dialog behind the scenes? To me it seems like it's just a fragment or activity

Comment: Yes it is a dialog. According to their github page here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md 
it extends `AlertDialog.Builder`

Comment: [Full-screen dialog](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#full-screen-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post